for the ffmpeg scale2ref filter, how do I repeat the last frame or loop the SHORTER video to match the duration of the longer video
I'm trying to scale2ref things in ffmpeg, but the problem is if the first input is shorter than the 2nd, there is no way I can find to make it match the longer input, without making any assumptions on which input is longer or the length. This is a user-facing application, so it should Just Work on any two videos.
I want this to be a pure FFMPEG solution without having to parse out the duration and re-input it with code, but if there is no other option I can do that
EDIT: after some debugging, it seems scale2ref is the culprit, not overlay. my ffmpeg isn't new enough to use the scale=rw:rh filter so I still need to use scale2ref.

try → ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i "input 2.mp4" -sseof -0.08 -i input.mp4 -lavfi " [2]loop=-1:1:0[c]; [0][c]concat=2:1:0[c]; [c][1]scale2ref[a][b]; [a][b]overlay=300:300:shortest=1 " out.mp4, where -sseof -0.08 -i input.mp4 is last frame for 25fps, maybe -0.04, but -0.08 works for me
