Set a minimum frame time for FFmpeg gifs
I'm converting videos into gifs with FFmpeg, but I'm running into an issue that many have encountered before: many gif players refuse to play gifs faster than 50FPS (2 hundredth of a second frame duration). The gif format technically allows up to 100FPS but not all players support that.
I have code now to limit the FPS to 50FPS, but the problem is that FFmpeg, when encoding from a weird fps like 29.97fps, will occasionally generate 1/100 s frames since each frame duration is independent.
I want to, ideally with a single ffmpeg command, generate a GIF of the right speed (not slowing down or speeding up) but without ever generating 1/100 s frames. Is this possible?
For Rotem, the code is just
    outname = reserve_tempfile("gif")
    fps = await get_frame_rate(video)
    await run_command("ffmpeg", "-i", video,
                      # prevent partial frames, makes filesize worse but fixes issues with transparency
                      "-gifflags", "-transdiff",
                      "-vf",
                      # cap fps because gifs are wackyyyyyy
                      # TODO: https://superuser.com/q/1854904/1001487
                      ("fps=fps=50," if fps > 50 else "") + \
                      # make and use nice palette
                      "split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen=reserve_transparent=1[p];[s1][p]paletteuse=bayer",
                      # i hate gifs so much man
                      "-fps_mode", "vfr",
                      outname)


Your wish to "generate a GIF of the right speed" seems impossible. According to Wikipedia: "The animation delay for each frame is specified in the GCE in hundredths of a second". With 0.01 seconds time resolution, the closest fps to 29.97fps (and to 30fps) is 33.33fps. In that case the frame delay is 0.03 seconds... Please explain if you like to get the closest possible FPS. Please show what you have tried so far (post the code that limits the FPS to 50FPS).

FFmpeg, by default, generates varying frame times to average out to the desired fps. This is the issue, that it can generate 10ms frames https://superuser.com/q/1459724/1001487

Ok I updated the post to have my code, but its nothing special

Assume the input FPS is 29.97fps, would you like the output FPS to be 33.33fps (best effort constant framerate), without frames duplication or dropping (assume the input has 100 frames, the output has 100 frames)?

no, i want ffmpeg to do what it normally does, it varies the frame time, sometimes duplicating/dropping, to reach the desired fps by averaging out the frame times, with the caveat of not allowing 10ms frames to be generated, only 20ms or more

It looks like FFmpeg doesn't support 100Hz, and replaces the rate to 10Hz. Example for 50Hz: ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=s=100x100:r=100:d=10 -filter_complex "split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse,setpts=N/50/TB" test50hz.gif and ffprobe -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -show_entries frame=pts_time test50hz.gif > 50hz.txt. The result is: 0, 0.02, 0.04...

Example for 100Hz: ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=s=100x100:r=100:d=10 -filter_complex "split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse,setpts=N/100/TB" test100hz.gif and ffprobe -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -show_entries frame=pts_time test100hz.gif > 100hz.txt. The result is: 0, 0.1, 0.2... It looks like FFmpeg replaces the 100fps with 10fps.

Example for mixed 50Hz and 100Hz: ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=s=100x100:r=100:d=10 -filter_complex "split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse,setpts='if(eq(N,0),0,if(mod(N,10),PREV_OUTPTS+0.02/TB,PREV_OUTPTS+0.01/TB))'" test50and100hz.gif and ffprobe -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -show_entries frame=pts_time test50and100hz.gif > 50and100hz.txt. The result is like 50Hz, but every 10 frames, timestamps jumps by 0.1 (like 10Hz). That means that each time frame delay is 10msec, FFmpeg sets the delay to 100msec. This behaviour is problematic, but doesn't match your question.
